# Why is the equivalent resistance in this circuit equal to 0.5 Ω?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, resistance

[image]

Using the Kennelly triangle transformation, why is the equivalent resistance between A and B here equal to 0.5 Ω given that r = 1 Ω?

Comment: Drawing A at the top and B at the bottom, the resistor bottom right becomes the horizontal resistor in the bridge.

Answer (score 1):

The middle resistor in the wheatstone setup can be removed as the nodal voltages corresponding to that resistance is the same. There will be no effect due to the middle resistance in the circuit. The parallel combination of the remaining resistors in the wheatstone setup will give you an equivalent resistance of *r*. The combination of this resistance with the resistance at the leftmost end will give *0.5r* which will be equal to **0.5**.

Comment: i forget to mention that the question is about the equivalent resistance between A and B is that still valid?

Comment: @user466932 Yes - if you redraw the circuit to have B as the node on the bottom, the circuit will look identical to yours, just with B not in the middle any more.

Comment: It seems you cannot remove the 1 ohm resistor as if you remove it, resistance between A and B would be 0.625 Ohm. If you keep the 1 ohm resistor as it is, the equivalent resistance between A and B is 0.5 ohm.

Comment: @AmitM yes thats what i thought also the use of the kennelly triangle is obligatory .

Comment: user466932, if the circuit is not easily analyzed by delta Y transformations or by symmetry.  connect a 1A current source at A and connect the negative end of the current source at B and connect B to ground. In this way, it is easy to find the thevenin resistance with nodal analysis by calculating \$V_A\$.
,